# Principal Component Analysis for data of circular dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What would be the formal way of performing PCA on data whose dimensionality is circular in nature. For example, I have a several 7-D data points of angles between $[-\pi,\pi]$. PCA is inherently suited for $R^n$ data points. How can I transform this data matrix so that the distances between the points are reflected along the circular dimension ?

I always find articles or forums which talk about nearest neighbour search for angles through certain tricks (e.g) transform to polar coordinates, etc. I am unable to see how this can be incorporated in the PCA framework.

Comment: What does "circular dimensionality" mean?

Comment: If you search the web for "circular statistics principal component analysis" you get some apparently relevant papers, e.g. https://dx.doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkr1069, https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2746330

Comment: By circular, I mean spherical coordinates on a plane (i.e) $S^1$, something like a clock. On the real space $-\pi$ and $\pi$ are far away but are the same on the circular dimension. @ChristopherHalverson

Comment: Thanks for the papers @Rahul